# How does the Patient Protection and Affordable Care Act (Obamacare) differ from Massachusetts health care reform (Romneycare)?

Tags: united-states, law, healthcare, affordable-care-act, massachusetts

These two laws at face value have many similarities, but it is difficult to spot the differences. How are these two bills alike, and how are they different?

Comment: One is 50 pages long, the other 900 pages. This is probably the main reason the differences are hard to spot. :-)

Comment: The most blatant one - Obamacare is federal, and Romneycare is not.  From a legal standpoint, this is a major distinction.

Answer (score 8):

The following list from [A Tale Of Two Health Plans: Romney Versus Obama](http://www.npr.org/2011/10/14/141357505/a-tale-of-two-health-plans-romney-versus-obama) answers this question pretty well.

> **Similarities**
>
> - Both have individual mandates that impose a tax penalty on people who
>     have the financial ability to buy insurance but don't. Federal
>     penalties start at $695 annually, or 2.5 percent of income, whichever
>     is higher. In Massachusetts, penalties range from $228 to $1,212,
>     depending on family size and income.
> - Both require health care "exchanges" (in Massachusetts, the exchange
>     is called the "connector") designed to create a competitive health
>     insurance market that gives individual and small business consumers a
>     choice of private plans, rules that facilitate price comparison and
>     plan transparency.
> - Both leave intact employer-provided insurance systems — Medicare
>     plans for the nation's seniors, and Medicaid for poor and low-income
>     citizens.
> - Both would fine companies that don't offer employee heath insurance,
>     with exceptions for small businesses. Massachusetts requires
>     companies with more than 10 employees to offer insurance; the
>     national law sets the limit at 50 employees.
> - Both provide subsidies to low-income individuals and families to help
>     pay for health insurance coverage.
>
> **Differences**
>
> - The federal plan has a stated goal of attempting to lower health care
>     costs; Massachusetts had no such stated goal.
> - The federal plan includes a patients' bill of rights, and provisions
>     designed to promote public health.
> - The federal plan includes the so-called CLASS Act, a voluntary insurance program offered to workers for long-term care in the event that they become disabled when they get older. (The Obama administration last week delayed the program's rollout because it isn't financially self-sustaining as designed.)
> - The federal plan would expand Medicaid to cover poor, able-bodied adults who are not parents in addition to poor children, elderly, pregnant women and those with disabilities. The Massachusetts plan expands Medicaid coverage to more children.
> - To pay for the new coverage, the federal plan imposes taxes on a variety of sectors, from drug and medical device makers to health insurers. Massachusetts relies largely on federal matching funds.